# ORA-00905: missing keyword, which keyword am I missing?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting an error

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

I am clueless what is wrong, all the KEYWORDS seem to be there. What am I missing? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE rep_contracts
(
    store_id NUMBER(8),
    name NUMBER(5),
    quarter CHAR(3),
    rep_id NUMBER(5),

    CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_rep_id_store_id_quarter_pk 
        PRIMARY KEY (rep_id, store_id, quarter),

    CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_rep_id_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (rep_id),
        REFERENCES book_stores (rep_id),

    CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_store_id_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (store_id),
        REFERENCES book_stores (store_id)
);
```

Comment: Remove the comma after the `FOREIGN KEY (...)` parts. The `REFERENCES` clause is part of the constraint definition not a new one.

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive, online and free. I suggest you bookmark the appropriate version. It will be easy for you to diagnose syntax errors like this by comparing your code with [the examples provided in the Oracle SQL Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/clauses002.htm#i1036780).

Answer (score 2):

You have commas in the middle of your `FOREIGN KEY` constraints, so oracle is complaining about the missing `REFERENCES` keyword. Remove the commas and the code works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE rep_contracts
(store_id NUMBER(8),
name NUMBER(5),
quarter CHAR(3),
rep_id NUMBER(5),

CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_rep_id_store_id_quarter_pk PRIMARY KEY (rep_id,store_id,quarter),

CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_rep_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (rep_id)
REFERENCES book_stores (rep_id),
CONSTRAINT rep_contracts_store_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (store_id)
REFERENCES book_stores (store_id));
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0dba84ce0f41aebca6d88062e10e5040)